# Core Data Delete only working intermittently

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've getting intermittent results on deletion. Sometimes the objects will delete, but most the time when I restart the project or even directly after the delete code, the store still pulls up instances of the objects. I'm deleting through a reference to `managedObjectContext` from the `AppDelegate` and making sure I save post delete.

```
   if let object = getById(id, context: context){
        context.deleteObject(object)
        do{
            print("Deleteing object by id")
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print("Unable to delete object for some reason")
        }
   }
```

If I run a `getById()` with the same id again right after I've successfully saved my deletion, it finds the object again. The error block never triggers, so I figure there is something else going wrong here. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: What does your `getById` function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Deleting was always working fine, the problem was that the identifiers to which I was fetching in my `getById()` method were not always unique. This caused intermittent deleting to occur because if there were 7 objects with id 1, than there was a 1/7 chance the first object was in fact the one I wished to be deleted.

Long story short, examine the whole problem, and don't make assumptions unless your sure in my case here, that the `getById()` was actually returning the desired object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are deleting the found object before entering the do loop and the context.save() is saving it back. That is probably the reason the Error block is not triggering when you look for the object.

try -

```
if let object = getById(id, context: context) {
  do {
      try context.deleteObject(object)
      try context.save() (I am still not sure if this statement should be there!!!)
      print()

}catch{
      print()
}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good thought, but it was something simple and stupid on my part, deleting was actually working fine.

Comment: That `do` is not a loop, it's there so that errors can be caught. The `catch` block would not execute unless the `save` method throws an error. And as for `save()`, how else would the code save changes if it weren't there?